# How to show interest to work for a potential employer

Tags: interviewing, resume, cover-letter, networking

I am interested in working for a particular organization (this is in US). The manager has asked via a friend of mine that I send (email) my CV to him. I have seen him a couple of times in the past. Now my questions are:

1. Would it be better to go and give him the CV in person instead, rather than sending it via email?
2. In either case, does it make sense to give him a cover letter as well, even if he has neither asked for it, nor is it clear which position I might get in his organization (if any)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to make contact. How depends on the distance and convenience of doing so. If you worked in the same building stopping by would make a lot of sense. If you have to drive an hour in the middle of the workday, that might not make as much sense.

A phone call can be a  nice compromise, you can be confirming the email address, or confirming the position description while making the initial contact. You can also ask what the next step in the process is. That will let you know what their time frame is for making a decision.

The cover letter can be used to show how perfect you are for the position, but that is hard to do if you don't know what the position is. The cover letter can be used to remind the manager who you are, how you know them, and who requested that you contact them. In this case you are using the cover letter to offer up somebody as a reference because that is the only reason why you are being considered.

Even if you deliver the CV and cover letter by hand, expect that they will want an electronic copy. Most companies will want to pass the resume to the proper person for the hiring process. They may want to store the document for a few weeks before making the decision.